# Iteratively subset and calculate means of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather large DataFrame (~30k rows, ~30k columns), for which I am trying to iteratively create two subsets based on every columns values, and store the ratio arrays for each column:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    high_subset = df.query(col>cutoff_vals['high'][col]).mean(axis=0)
    low_subset = df.query(col<cutoff_vals['low'][col]).mean(axis=0)
    ratios = high_subset / low_subset
    ///
    store_ratios_for_col
```

I have the `low_cutoff` and `high_cuttoff` values precomputed and stored in a dictionary `cutoff_vals`. I would like to be able to store the `ratio` array for every column, which should result in a NxN array of ratios (N == number of columns).

Is there a more efficient method to iterate through the columns, subset them, and perform math/comparisons on the results Series?

I understand that using something like Dask or Ray-project may help, but thought there may be a clever vectorization or built in pandas trick first.

Answer (score 2):

Use `gt` to compare all the columns, then `.where` to mask:

```
cutoffs = pd.DataFrame(cutoff_vals)

highs = df.where(df.gt(cutoffs['high'])).mean()
lows = df.where(df.lt(cutoffs['low'])).mean()

# ratios for all columns
# get any with ratios[col_name]
ratios = highs / lows
```

Comment: This stores the high/low ratio for each subset, but collapses down to only the ratio for the given column. Is there a way to edit this so that I can store the ratio array for _each_ subset? I'm imagining this should be a NxN array instead of a single dimensional array.

Comment: Maybe you should add a sample data and expected output to your question.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question with expected output.